# How to add multiple empty columns (no names) to a dataframe? To export to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## The issue

I have a dataframe which summarises certain data, and I am exporting it to Excel.

There is a logical order to the columns, whereby it would be useful to separate certain blocks: e.g. first 3 columns related to a, then an empty column as separator, then 2 columns related to b, then an empty column as separator, then to block related to c, etc.

I can do `df[' ']= None` and it works, I have an empty column which acts as a separator, but if I repeat the command Python will replace the column I had already created, it won't add a new one.

I would like to  create a dataframe which would look like this when exported to Excel (note the 4th and 6th columns are blank and act as separators):

[image: Excel screenshot]

## Why I need it

I need to export to Excel the results in the dataframe. The output is some kind of report, not, say, a file which will be imported into a database and which therefore cannot have empty columns. Readability is key and separating the blocks with empty columns helps readability because it makes it easier to find when a block ends and when another starts.

## My partial solution

The only solution I have found is to manually remember how many empty columns I have already added and create columns whose name = a certain number of white spaces. E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.arange(0,10)
df[' '] = None # 1 white space
df['b'] = 5
df['  '] = None # 2 white spaces
df['c'] = 10
```

It works, but the problem with this is that it is prone to errors, because I often have to reshuffle the blocks around, and in reality I have, many, many blocks, not just 3 as in this toy example.

## What I have found

I understand that pandas allows non-unique columns https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/duplicates.html . I can create such a dataframe if I specify the columns upfront:
`df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c','b'])` but I have not figured out how to add duplicate columns one by one. That would be useful because I'm often reshuffling the order of the columns, so it's easier for me to have

```
df['a'] = something
df['c']= something_else
```

than defining everything in one statement

## The questions

1. Is there a better way than remembering how many separator columns I have created, and first creating one with 1 whitespace as column name, then one with 2, then one with 3 etc?
2. Is there a way to add a duplicate column after having already created the dataframe?
3. Anything else you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

If possible recreate new columns with one or multiple spaces from original columns use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.arange(0,10)
df['b'] = 5
df['c'] = 10

df1 = df.reindex(columns=['a',' ','b','  ','c'])
print (df1)

   a      b       c
0  0 NaN  5 NaN  10
1  1 NaN  5 NaN  10
2  2 NaN  5 NaN  10
3  3 NaN  5 NaN  10
4  4 NaN  5 NaN  10
5  5 NaN  5 NaN  10
6  6 NaN  5 NaN  10
7  7 NaN  5 NaN  10
8  8 NaN  5 NaN  10
9  9 NaN  5 NaN  10
```

Also is possible duplicated columns names, e.g. here `''`:

```
df2 = df.reindex(columns=['a','','b','','c'])
print (df2)
   a      b       c
0  0 NaN  5 NaN  10
1  1 NaN  5 NaN  10
2  2 NaN  5 NaN  10
3  3 NaN  5 NaN  10
4  4 NaN  5 NaN  10
5  5 NaN  5 NaN  10
6  6 NaN  5 NaN  10
7  7 NaN  5 NaN  10
8  8 NaN  5 NaN  10
9  9 NaN  5 NaN  10
```

If necessary you can drop them.

```
df = df2.drop('', axis=1)
print (df)
   a  b   c
0  0  5  10
1  1  5  10
2  2  5  10
3  3  5  10
4  4  5  10
5  5  5  10
6  6  5  10
7  7  5  10
8  8  5  10
9  9  5  10
```

Solution with remember last space(s):

```
last = ' '
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.arange(0,10)
df[last] = None # 1 white space

last = last + ' '
df['b'] = 5
df[last] = None # 2 white spaces
last = last + ' '

df['c'] = 10

print (df.columns)
Index(['a', ' ', 'b', '  ', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Btw, why are not recommended duplicated columns names is because if select one get all columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.arange(0,10)
df['b'] = 5
df['c'] = 10


df2 = df.reindex(columns=['a','','b','','c', 'a', 'a'])
print (df2)
   a      b       c  a  a
0  0 NaN  5 NaN  10  0  0
1  1 NaN  5 NaN  10  1  1
2  2 NaN  5 NaN  10  2  2
3  3 NaN  5 NaN  10  3  3
4  4 NaN  5 NaN  10  4  4
5  5 NaN  5 NaN  10  5  5
6  6 NaN  5 NaN  10  6  6
7  7 NaN  5 NaN  10  7  7
8  8 NaN  5 NaN  10  8  8
9  9 NaN  5 NaN  10  9  9
```

---

```
print (df2[''])
         
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN
8 NaN NaN
9 NaN NaN

print (df2['a'])
   a  a  a
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5
6  6  6  6
7  7  7  7
8  8  8  8
9  9  9  9
```

EDIT: Is it possible to add a duplicate column in a specific position of the dataframe?

With [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) not, need unique column name. Also there is trick if create new column in another `insert` is also count previous created column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.arange(0,10)
df['b'] = 5
df['c'] = 10

df.insert(1, '', None)

df.insert(3, ' ', None)
print (df)
   a        b         c
0  0  None  5  None  10
1  1  None  5  None  10
2  2  None  5  None  10
3  3  None  5  None  10
4  4  None  5  None  10
5  5  None  5  None  10
6  6  None  5  None  10
7  7  None  5  None  10
8  8  None  5  None  10
9  9  None  5  None  10
```

Another idea is create MultiIndex for grouping columns, e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.arange(0,10)
df['b'] = 5
df['c'] = 10

groups = {'g1':['a','b'], 'g2':['c']}

d = {x: k for k, v in groups.items() for x in v}

df.columns = [df.columns.map(d), df.columns]
print (df)
  g1     g2
   a  b   c
0  0  5  10
1  1  5  10
2  2  5  10
3  3  5  10
4  4  5  10
5  5  5  10
6  6  5  10
7  7  5  10
8  8  5  10
9  9  5  10
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a duplicate column in a specific position of the dataframe? I have many dozen columns, many of which are actually created by the methods of a class, and listing them manually one by one for the reindex would be tedious and somewhat error-prone

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous - Added to answer. But honestly why not use `MultiIndex` for create groups?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the '[DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html?highlight=to_excel#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel)' method, then I would use the columns argument. This allows you to specify the order in which the columns will be written and allows you to write the same column multiple times.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df[' '] = None
df.to_excel(file_name, columns=['A', ' ', ' ', 'B'])
```

In this code, the output file should contain two empty columns between A and B.
If you don't want to specify all the columns by hand, you can also do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
SEPARATOR = ' '
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
# Get original columns (before adding the empty one)
df_columns = list(df.columns)
df[SEPARATOR] = None
# Modify the columns to add empty columns in the desired positions
df_columns.insert(1, SEPARATOR)
df_columns.insert(2, SEPARATOR)
df.to_excel(file_name, columns=df_columns)
```

(I used this code with .ods files and works fine, I will assume works also for Excel files)

If this doesn't work for you, you can also use the [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to keep track of the number of spaces like this:

```
import itertools
# Create an iterator that yields integers, starting with 1
count = itertools.count(1)
def add_empty_column(df):
    n = next(count)
    df[' ' * n] = None
```